# Grails: can we pass string as id in g:link? Or any other way?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Scenario:
I want to create `g:link` which will redirect to

```
www.xyz.com/controller/action/title_of_question
```

instead

```
www.xyz.com/controller/action/id_of_question
```

I know that later one can be created easily configuring `id` param of the `g:link`.
Please note that `title_of_question` is `String` separated with hyphen (-)
Can anybody suggest me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, we can :)

If you have no rule in `UrlMappings.groovy` which defines `id` as `Long` or `Integer` you can create links with `String` identifier like below:

```
<g:link controller="controllerName" action="show" id="someName">Link!</g:link>
```

And define controllers action with identifier as `String`:

```
def show(String id) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is create a new Action in your controller that takes your ID, and redirects your to the URL you are trying to goto.

```
<g:link resource="book" action="name" id="${id}">New Book</g:link>
```

then in your controller.

```
def name(int id) {
    //take the ID, get the name, and redirect to the proper .gsp.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing the following:

```
def someAction() {
    if(params.id.matches(/[0-9]+/)) {
        //logic for id of question
    } else {
        //you could check if it is separated with dashes
        //logic for title of question
    }
}
```

This would trigger the id logic:

```
www.xyz.com/controller/someAction/15
```

And this the 'title' logic:

```
www.xyz.com/controller/someAction/title-of-question
```